# Windows 10 REtail on OEM laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, windows-activation, oem

There’s a possibility that this type of question might have been asked before, but I am not able to find the exact reference on this site.

Soon I am going to buy a laptop with Windows 10 OEM. (Most likely Acer brand) Generally such laptops do have a special recovery partition to refresh/reinstall Windows if the need be. The vendors also provide some app to take an offline image of OS on to a USB Pen drive so that if necessary the OEM OS can be installed from that USB drive to get back the laptop to factory default state.

However if I don’t create such an offline USB image and in the event my HDD crashes, then I have lost my OEM Windows 10 on it.

I am aware that service center generally provides reactivated OEM Windows for a small fee in such cases. However instead of going to the service center, can a downloaded Windows 10 from Microsoft accept the OEM key embedded in the UEFI Firmware and proceed with successful install & activation on such an OEM Windows 10 Laptop or will it refuse to install in the first place, or will it demand a new retail key before successful activation?

Any clarity on this matter would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

Any hardware windows 8 or above will automatically activate a copy of windows 10, pro or home depending on the authorized version for that machine.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you back this up with sources? :)

Comment: No because I simply know it from experience, but any piece of hardware that has a windows 8 or higher sticker on activates windows 10 automatically (I have installed thousands).  If its a piece of hardware with a windows 7 key on it then you can use that key to activate windows 10 as long as it is not in use by anyone else.  You have to use the equivalent version of windows 10 ie. home or pro.